# function inside the python class is not called while running the server

Tags: python, django, validation, django-forms, forms-authentication

i am trying to validate unique user name in the registration form. while i click the submit button after entering the details in the register form, instead of raising a validation error with the given message, it fails and errors out Validationerror at /register/. i am also trying to print the string inside the function. but it doesnt print that too. is it actually calling the clean function. i am using self to achieve this. it should be called !. am i misiing something?

```
class Register_Form(forms.Form):


    user_id = forms.CharField(label="User Name",widget = forms.TextInput(
                                attrs = {"class":"form-control"}
                                ))

    email_id = forms.CharField(label = "Email",widget = forms.EmailInput(
                                attrs = {"class":"form-control"}
                                ))

    password = forms.CharField(label = "Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput(
                                attrs = {"class":"form-control"}
                                ))
    confirm_pass = forms.CharField(label = "Confirm Password",widget = forms.PasswordInput(
                                attrs = {"class":"form-control"}
                                ))

     def clean_username(self):
         user_id = self.cleaned_data["user_id"]
         print("Entered")
         ue = User.objects.filter(username=user_id)
         if ue.exists():
             raise forms.ValidationError("User name not available")
         return user_id
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not being called, the fact you pass self doesn't mean it'll automatically run, you are just extending your function with self so that it can inherit it's attributes.

Somewhere inside your class you'll have to run `self.clean_username()`, alternatively if you construct the class, e.g. `RF = Register_Form()` you'll have to call `RF.clean_username()`